# Need to put my formula into a graph in R

Tags: r, statistics

```
vi=c(5.0e-10, 1.25e-9, 2.5e-9, 5.0e-9, 1.25e-8, 2.5e-8, 5.0e-8)
ni=c(76, 75, 72, 71, 72, 69, 69)
xi=c(75, 69, 58, 51, 23, 11, 2)
lambda = 65700813

# Define the product binomial log likelihood function.
lnlike = function(lambda, Vi, Xi, Ni) {
  
sum(lfactorial(Ni)-lfactorial(Xi)-lfactorial(Ni-Xi)-(Ni)+(Xi)*(-lambda*Vi)+(Ni-Xi)*log(1-exp(-lambda*Vi)))

}

lambdalo = 20000000  # Lower boundary of the interval for the objective function
lambdahi = 83000000  # Upper boundary of the interval for the objective function

# R function optimize():  one-dimensional optimization function.
ML = optimize(f = lnlike, Vi = vi, Ni = ni, Xi = xi,
               lower = lambdalo, upper = lambdahi,
               maximum = TRUE)
lambda = ML$maximum               #  ML estimate of lambda.
log.likelihood = ML$objective   #  Maximized log-likelihood.


# Print the results.
lambda
log.likelihood

# Calculate virus count curve as well as observed virus
# probabilities for plotting.
nn = seq(5000000,10000000,10000)
act.virus = 1-(-lambda*nn)
obs.probs  = xi/ni
act.virus
# Plot the results.
plot(nn, act.virus, type = "l", pch = 1, cex = 1.5,
     xlab = "lambda", ylab = "ML lambda")
points(ni, obs.probs, type = "p", col="purple")
```